# Is it possible to use a virtual machine created for a particular OS in ubuntu in windows as well?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I want to install a virtual machine (say virtual box) on windows to run ubuntu as guest OS. And right now I'm using ubuntu OS.

Can I install ubuntu OS on a virtual machine in ubuntu and can the same virtual machine be used on windows as well? If that is possible, why are there different versions of virtual machines for different OS? I mean, how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Hurry... your question will be frozen soon by the mods here 
:) All the best buddy.

Detailed answer here;

https://superuser.com/questions/399105/is-a-vdi-file-for-virtualbox-cross-platform